# Why doesn't Moq see this method being invoked in .Select method?

Tags: c#, moq

I created this gist to describe what's happening:

https://gist.github.com/IanRandall/5417410

briefly:  The .Verify assertion is failing in the first implementation of .Get() method on the repository, as Moq is not noticing that the mapper is being called.

Anyone else seen this? Am I missing something?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic IEnumerable concept error.

You're returning an iterator with the linq query.  The iterator won't actually call the function until you iterate over it.

If you did this (for example), you should see it work, as it forces the iteration:

```
return results.Select(entity => _mapper.Transform(entity)).ToList();
```